# How to fix non-coplannar polygons?

Tags: polygon, plane

I have a 3-D object described by surface facets. It is saved as OFF file. However, some of the vertices in a surface facet (polygon) are not exactly coplannar. Is there any good idea to fix these non-coplannar polygons to let them become coplannar?
My idea is 
1) for every polygon, find the base plane of the polygon that most vertices fall into the plane, for example, the distance of vertex to the plane is less than machine precision (but how to find this base plane?);
2) for these vertices that are not fall into the base plane of the polygon, find the intersection of vertex's associated polygons' base planes and take it as the new location of this vertex.

Is there any problem? Do you have any better idea?

Thanks,
Tang Laoya

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should concentrate on fixing quadrilaterals, and repeat that over and over. Say two adjacent triangles have vertices abc and cbd, sharing edge bd.
Compute the volume of the tetrahedron abcd, and if it is small, decided to flatten. Or, maybe better, compute the dihedral angle at bd and flatten if
near pi; yes, that is probably a better measure.

Once you decide you would like to repair abcd, project d to the plane determined by abc, and replace d with that projected point. Now abcd are coplanar. You could do this for all the permutations and replace the point that moves the least.

Unfortunately, it seems this is order-dependent and could lead to cycles when
repeated over and over on all pairs of triangles.